# How to add month archive into menu with seven diffrent div in wordpress

Tags: function, menu, wordpress

Can anyone know how to add month archive in menu with some custom value of different part.
here wordpress filter to add in menu.

```
function add_archive($items, $args) {
    $items1 .= '<a href="#">archives</a><ul class="sub-menu">';
    $items1 .= get_archives('monthly', '12', 'custom','<li>','</li>', FALSE,0);
    $items1 .= '</ul></li>';
    return str_replace('<a href="#">archives</a></li>',$items1,$items);

}
?>
```

The HTML output i'm looking for archive menu as follows...

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-619" id="menu-item-619">
    <a href="#">Archive</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
        <div class="drop-dowm">
            <div><a href="/2015/05">May 2015</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2015/04">April 2015</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2015/03">March 2015</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2015/02">February 2015</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2015/01">January 2015</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/12">December 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/11">November 2013</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-dowm">
            <div><a href="/2013/10">October 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/09">September 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/08">August 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/07">July 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/06">June 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/05">May 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/04">April 2013</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="drop-dowm">
            <div><a href="/2013/03">March 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2013/02">February 2013</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2012/10">October 2012</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2012/06">June 2012</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2012/05">May 2012</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2012/03">March 2012</a></div>
            <div><a href="/2011/12">December 2011</a></div>
        </div>
    </ul>
</li>
```

plz help..

Comment: What works, what doesn't? This isn't a magic code fixer site, it is supposed to help you help yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here i got solution for my own question. may it help other.

```
<?php 
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_archive');
function add_archive($items, $args) {

    $l = 0; 
    $ar = '';
    $ar = '';
    $ar .= '<li class="parent-category"><a href="#">archives</a><ul class="sub-menu">';
    global $wpdb;
    $months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH( post_date ) AS month , YEAR( post_date ) AS year, COUNT( id ) as post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' and post_date <= now( ) and post_type = 'post' GROUP BY month , year ORDER BY post_date DESC");

    foreach($months as $month) 
    {

        if($l==0)
        {
            $ar .= '<div class="drop-dowm">';
        }
        elseif($l % 7 ==0)
        {
            $ar .= '</div><div class="drop-dowm">';
        }

        $ar .= '<div>';                 
        $ar .= '<a href="'.get_bloginfo('url').'/'. $month->year.'/'.$month->name.date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)).'">'.date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)).'&nbsp;&nbsp;'. $month->year.'</a>';

        $ar .= '</div>';
        $l++;   

    }                       

    $ar .= '</ul></li>';

    $items1 .= $ar;
    return str_replace('<a href="#">archives</a></li>',$items1,$items);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `return` calls

You are appending to `$items1` without declaring it.

Most importantly, you haven't specified what problem you're facing.